# how to add a string after each comma in UITextfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Im lookin a way to add # at the beginig of each word written in uiTextField with swift, i tryes to check using this code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   if  textField.text!.first != "#" {
        print(textField.text!.first)
        print(textField.text!)
        textField.text = ""
   }
}
```

but the firsrt character is nil when the input on keyboard is # so what should be the way to achive this having all the words begins with # and separated by ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it easier checking the text after editing changed control event and clean your string when the user types a space after each word. You can subclass your UITextField and it should look something like this:

```
class TagsField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        delegate = self
        keyboardType = .alphabet
        autocapitalizationType = .none
        autocorrectionType = .no
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        prepareString()
        if text!.hasSuffix(", #") { text!.removeLast(3) } // clean the residue on end
        resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    func prepareString() {
        text = text!.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted)   // filtering non letters and grouping words
                .filter{!$0.isEmpty}           // filtering empty components
                .map{ "#" + $0 + ", " }        // add prefix and sufix to each word and append # to the end of the string
                .string + "#" 

    }
    override func deleteBackward() {
        let _ = text!.popLast()    // manually pops the last character when deliting
    }
    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if text!.last == " " {
            prepareString()
        } else if !text!.hasPrefix("#") {  // check if the first word being typed has the # prefix and add it if needed.
            text!.insert("#", at: text!.startIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection where Element: StringProtocol {
    var string: String {
        return String(joined())
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `.joined().dropLast(2) + " " `

Comment: Doesn't `.dropLast() + " "` just remove a space and then add it back?

Comment: @Carpsen90 you are correct. it is pointless. It is actually a residue. just removed

Comment: Sorry to bother you again: `CharacterSet.letters.inverted` limits the possible tags : `#swift4` wouldn't be possible. Maybe `CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted` would be more appropriate for hashtags?

Comment: I haven't thought about numerics but sure this will depend on OP requirements

Comment: You need to move the contains check out of that iff condition will only get there if Int(text) successes.